# How to override tailwind colors in runtime

Tags: javascript, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-in-js

I'm using tailwind v3 and according to the docs, it's possible to override existing colors using the `tailwind.config` file

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/customizing-colors

```
module.exports = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                gray: {
                    "50": "#fcefed",
                    "100": "#fadedb",
                    "200": "#f7ceca",
                    "300": "#f5bdb8",
                    "400": "#f2ada6",
                    "500": "#ef9d94",
                    "600": "#ed8c82",
                    "700": "#ea7c71",
                    "800": "#e86b5f",
                    "900": "#e55b4d"
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I want to override the color palette when a user clicks on a button.
How can I override it during runtime? Ideally, I could use the same convention as the tailwind config file, something like that:

```
    //user click on a button
    const onColorsPicked = () => {
        const colors = {
            "50": "#fcefed",
            "100": "#fadedb",
            "200": "#f7ceca",
            "300": "#f5bdb8",
            "400": "#f2ada6",
            "500": "#ef9d94",
            "600": "#ed8c82",
            "700": "#ea7c71",
            "800": "#e86b5f",
            "900": "#e55b4d"
        }
        //what would be the best approach to implement this function? it's even possible?
        overrideTailwindColor("gray", colors)
    }
```

Not sure if the just-in-time-mode could help or not (https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode)

What would be the best approach to do that?
There are any CSS variables I can override instead? Or I should get all the classes that tailwind could generate and override them? (sounds like a huge overkill)

Comment: Css variables...

Comment: could you provide more information?

Comment: I am still a bit in the dark about what you are trying but if you are trying to implement a feature similar to dark mode on a page you could add all necessary colors ahead of time and switch them out via `class` modifications in JS.

Comment: not something like dark mode, more like a theme, just trying to override a color palette in runtime and not in build @wp78de

Comment: You've answered your own question - use CSS variables and override them

Answer (score 2):

Instead of hardcoding the color variables inside tailwind.conf.js use CSS variables like below:

```
module.exports = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: {
                gray: {
                    "50": "var(--gray-50)",
                    "100": "var(--gray-100)",
                    .
                    .
                    . 
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Now you are able to change those CSS variables with JS whenever you want.